# Bcp must be installed error when loading Adventureworks Azure datawarehouse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I'm trying to test the Azure Data Warehouse. I successfully created and connected to the database, but I've run into a snag as I attempt to load the tables. I'm trying to execute the following instructions:

```
To install AdventureWorksSQLDW2012:
-----------------------------------

4. Extract files from AdventureWorksSQLDW2012.zip file into a directory.

5. Edit aw_create.bat setting the following variables:
   a. server=<servername> from step 1.  e.g. mylogicalserver.database.windows.net 
   b. user=<username> from step 1 or another user with proper permissions
   c. password=<passwordname> for user in step 5b
   d. database=<database> created in step 1
   e. schema=<schema> this schema will be created if it does not yet exist

6. Run aw_create.bat from a cmd prompt, running from the directory where the files were unzipped to.
   This script will...
   a. Drop any Adventure Works tables or views that already exist in the schema
   b. Create the Adventure Works tables and views in the schema specified
   c. Load each table using bcp
   d. Validate the row counts for each table
   e. Collect statistics on every column for each table
```

I completed the prerequisites of installing bcp and sqlcmd and used the -? command to confirm the installations.

Unfortunately, when I try to complete step 6 above I get the following error:

**REM AdventureWorksSQLDW2012 sample database version 3.0 for DW Service Tue 06/27/2017 20:31:01.99 Bcp must be installed.**

Has anyone else come across this error or can anyone suggest a potential solution.

UPDATE:  I've also copied the path where BCP is located to my path environment variables.   Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The aw_create.bat contains a line where you need to provide the path of the bcp program.  Once provided ans save the script worked like a charm.